# Cant screenshot model viewer

Tags: 3d, screenshot, gltf

I use model viewer library to show 3d model in my website

And try use html2canvas to get screenshot

Html2canvas work perfect with img and divs..

Why it didnt work with 3d model? [this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVde7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$("#capture").click(function () {
                var bottleCanvas = document.getElementById('viewer');
                var dataURL = bottleCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                var anchor = document.createElement('a');
                anchor.href = dataURL;
                anchor.download = 'screenshot.png';
                anchor.innerHTML = '<img width="100" height="100" src=' + dataURL + '>download';
                document.getElementById('images').appendChild(anchor);
            });
```